# CSS3 Hanging animation

Tags: css

Is there a way to achieve a hanging animation of an element bouncing up and down using `margin-top`? Something that imitates elastic.

Basically i want the first frame to be `margin-top:0px`, the second frame: `margin-top:15px;` and should be infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of example on the web.

Check it out from this [tutorial](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/bouncing-ball-animation/). It is done with pure CSS.

---

I just created a simple demo. Check it out. This one runs on both `webkit` and `mozilla` browsers.

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
       from{ -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px); }
       to { -webkit-transform: translate(0px,-30px); }  
      }

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
       from { -moz-transform: translate(0px,0px); }
       to { -moz-transform: translate(0px,-30px); }  
      }

.bounce{
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background:#ff0000;
    border-radius:20px;
    margin:50px;
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
        -webkit-animation-duration:.3s;
        -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
        -webkit-animation-delay:0s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-name: bounce;
        -moz-animation-duration:.3s;
        -moz-animation-direction:alternate;
        -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
        -moz-animation-delay:0s;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
```

#### [Check out this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/jHrmE/1)

Hope you like it.